# how to parse Turkish charactern in an xml response on iOS

Tags: xml, ios

I am getting some Turkish characters in an xml response. That causes some exceptions.

Can anybody tell me how can handle this?

Comment: Please provide the text of any exceptions generated along with the faulting code and the input that triggers the fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Convert it into UTF8

```
NSData *data = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then parse with this data...

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Comment: actually i am getting  the word like ÇORUM.and  i need to pass it to server and get response from server.but the word which contains turkish character returns with no data.so how should i pass it to server.